# How does the writing process work in h5py Datasets?

Tags: python, io, hdf5, h5py

I am using the following syntax to overwrite part of an hdf5 file in Python:

```py
import h5py

f = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')
dset = f["mykey"]
dset[:3] = [1,2,3]
f.close()
```

It seems to be working but I could not find information in the documentation about how this update is made. I am wondering if the dataset is (1) loaded in memory, (2) updated, (3) entirely written back, or if it just updates the piece of data on disk.

I am asking this because I want to recode it for npy files and I have the choice between loading the data, updating it and rewriting it or just using seek and making only the necessary update on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So have you studied the `h5py` docs, especially the page about datasets?  It's all there.

Here's what I've deduced from reading those docs and answering a variety of SO.

```
f = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')
dset = f["mykey"]
```

`dset` is the dataset object, that's located on the file.

```
arr = dset[:]
```

would load the dataset into a numpy array.

```
dset[:3] = [1,2,3]
```

this on the other hand, writes `np.array([1,2,3])` to the dataset on the file; that is, it will modify the first 3 elements of the file object.

```
f.close()
```

Due to buffering etc, that write might not actually happen until the `f` is `flushed` or `closed`.

Since it is possible to load just a portion of the dataset

```
arr = dset[:3]
```

I deduce it can perform the write without loading the whole `dset`.  The actual code is a mix of python, c++, with `cython` as the bridge.

Comment: OK thank you for your answer. I did read the docs but I could not find a line specifically saying that so I guessed it was working like this but I was not sure so thank you for your help.